# server takes too much time to upload the multiple images in android

Tags: android, performance, optimization, file-upload, android-gallery

My android app is uploading single as well multiple images on server .
If i upload single image then there is no problem , but if i select multiple images (8-10)
it takes lot of time to upload on server .

Please help me out .

```
class asyncImageUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    String methodName = "UploadImageWithDetail" ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();


        progressDialog = LoginActivity.createProgressDialog(CaseDetailsActivity.this);
        //progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CaseDetailsActivity.this);
        //progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i = 0 ; i<arrImagePath.size() ; i++)
        {

             try{

                    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 2;

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrImagePath.get(i), options);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, 600, true);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight());
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, buffer);
                    imageByteStr = Base64.encodeToString(buffer.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginID",sharedPreferences.getString("username", "")));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginKey", sharedPreferences.getString("password", "")));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("HostCompID", sharedPreferences.getString("hostID", "")));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginCompID",  sharedPreferences.getString("logID", "")));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caseID", caseId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("byteImageString", imageByteStr));

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(RxOfficeUtilities.URL+methodName);

            try {

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Comment: but what is your problem....this is obvious that if 1 pic takes 2 sec to upload then 10 pics ll take around 14 - 20 seconds or more....

Comment: @Rohit look , its fine with single image that it take 2-3 sec , but while uploading multiple it takes 2-3 min , progress dialoge goes on...

Comment: Please tell a little bit more about the server. You are not prividing a name for how the image has to be saved on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that rather than creating a http client in every loop try to use one http client.
Also close your buffer at the of each loop or try resetting it.

Comment: thats working fine , but one problem is still take time (better than first code .)

Comment: Have you tried logging the times? place different timing point in your code and see which one on average takes longer. By the way try reusing some of your objects rather than creating a new one. GC sometimes can slow down your application significantly

Comment: Indeed. Specifically for the Bitmap. Reuse it and/or try `bitmap.recycle()`.